# another version of "have somebody do something"

Tags: grammar

I understand the usage of `have somebody do something`

However, a [post](https://oklahoman.com/article/feed/336656/websites-to-blackout-over-over-anti-piracy-bill) says

> anti-piracy legislation under consideration in Washington **has** some websites in a tizzy.

There is no "do" there, is this another pattern or just omitting some verb?

Comment: The sense is 'has caused them to be in a tizzy'.

Comment: Same syntax as *The stand-up comedian **had** his audience in stitches.* Compare and contrast  1: *The vicar had the congregation stand up to sing a hymn* and 2: *The comedian had half the audience walk out when he told a very rude joke.* Just because the subject ***had*** the object do something doesn't mean that's what the subject ***wanted*** the object to do.

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica Thank you. `A has B do something` means A wants B do that; `A has C in ...` doesn't necessarily mean A wants C become that, right?

Comment: No, the potential difference in meaning *doesn't* depend on whether the "complement" is verb-based *(A had B **do / doing** something)*, or preposition-based *(A had B **in** tears)*. It's primarily just a matter of *context*, but I think the choice of verb form can make a difference. It's normally *The happy-clappy vicar had the congregation **dancing** in the aisles*, implying they ***spontaneously*** got up and danced. Whereas using the unmarked infinitive form *(...had them **dance**...),* more strongly implies the vicar explicitly ***urged / forced*** them to get up and boogiie.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an excerpt from the [Wiktionary definition of "have"](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/have#English) (and the definitions are surprisingly close to each other, which makes this good here):

[image]

The usage you're thinking of (*have somebody do something*) applies to definition (14).

> **Have** him call me later.    *AKA: **Command him to** / **Request that he** call me later.*

The usage the post is using applies to definition (15).

> The speech **had** people upset. *AKA: The speech **caused** people **to be** upset.*

Hopefully this is helpful to you.